# Regular Expression - Finding and replace text between nodes in one step

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to find all text inside a  node and take the matched text and replace the contents of a  node using only a single regular expression?  I should say that this is in a file.

Given:

```
<x>This text</x>
<!-- Unknown number of nodes between <x> and <y> -->
<y>Junk</y>
```

Change to:

```
<x>This text</x>
<!-- Unknown number of nodes between <x> and <y> -->
<y>This text</y>
```

Normally, I would do a regular expression to find the contents of x and store it in a variable. Then, I would run a second regular expression to find the contents of y and replace it with the variable's data.  Just wondering if there is a "1-step" solution...  Thanks.

Comment: [Do not parse XML with regular expressions!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to contact a friend about this.

The regEx, assuming only one x and one y node, would look like this.

```
s/X([^X]*)X([^Y]*)Y([^Y]*)Y/X\1X\2Y\1Y/
```

where X is `<x>` and Y is `<y>`

Comment: you can't use strings in character classes that way (re: `[^<x>]`)

Answer (score 3):

If you use JQuery, you could simply do this:

```
$('y').html($('x').html());
```

Otherwise, with standard JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('y')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('x')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Oops, this is in an XML file, so I couldn't use jQuery.  I'll updated the tag for "Perl"

Answer (score 2):

```
$filecontents =~ s!(<x>(?>(.*?)</x>)(?>.*?<y>))(?>.*?(</y>))!$1$2$3!s;
```

But you are better off using an XML parser (assuming this is XML).  For instance, the above won't work with your sample text, because it will think the `<y>` in the comment is the beginning of the y tag.

Comment: that's what they're for.  \K would help too, but I didn't want to assume 5.10+

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string that you want to replace, this seems to work.

```
<script>
    var text = "<x>This text<x>\n<y>Junk<y>";
    var replaced = text.replace(/<x>(.*)<x>\n<y>.*<y>/s, "<x>$1</x>\n<y>$1</y>");
    alert(replaced);
</script>
```

Comment: The dot loses its special meaning in character classes, so `[.\n]` matches a dot or a newline; you probably want another `.*` there.  And you should use the `s` modifier, not `m`.  Then the regex should work, but with all those greedy `.*`s, you might find it unacceptably slow. (That's assuming `<x>` and `<y>` are unique, but the OP says they are.)

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the correction. I edited the code, but I guess the question is not about javascript anymore..